# Efficient way to use Repeated K-fold cross-validation along with grid search using sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization, scikit-learn, outliers

I am intended to know the impact of outlier analysis on SVR's performance. So, I need to have two versions of SVR model: Version_1 with all the original dataset, Version_2 with just the non-outlier cases from same dataset. For the validation and SVR's parameter optimization I am using RepeatedKFold and GridSearch. For both Versions of SVR, I am required to use the same fold (so in case of Version_2 the outlier cases will be omitted/ removed from the same fold which has been used for Version_1 SVR).

How can I efficiently achieve this with RepeatedKFold and GridSearch, assuming outlier cases' indexes are stored in another list?